# How to recognize one-hot encoded columns in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning, one-hot-encoding

In pandas data frame there are multiple binary features columns with binary values, and the challenge is to identify which column has one-hot labels/values(which column can be a part of the one-hot encoded vector) and which column is an independent feature and not a part of one-hot encoded labels/vector.

The data that I need to clean and preprocess somehow looks like this:

```
Rows   v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  v9  v10 Label

0      1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0
1      0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0     0
2      0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0.5 0     0
3      0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1     0
4      0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     1
5      0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0     1
6      0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1     1
7      0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0.2 0     0
8      0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1     0
```

Note:  Need to find out a specific combination of columns in which we have one 1 and other zeros in a row which is as there can be some non-hotEncoded/independent binary columns.

By **specific combination of columns in which we have one 1 and other zeros in a row**, I mean a result/final combination of columns like this, where we have one 1 in a row(by excluding the other binary columns):

```
v1  v4  v5  v6  v7

1   0   0   0   0  
0   0   0   0   1   
0   1   0   0   0   
0   0   0   1   0 
0   0   1   0   0 
0   0   0   0   1  
0   1   0   0   0  
0   0   1   0   0 
0   0   0   1   0
```

Comment: That would have exactly one 1 per col? So, `df.loc[:,df.sum(0)==1]`?

Comment: No, one 1 in a row(in a specific combination of columns, that we have to find out).

Comment: `v9` is not binary. Do you wish to treat it as binary or to exclude from binary columns? Also, I understand your question but if you want better answers, you should explain what you mean by one-hot factors.

Comment: @Ehsan I have improved my question kindly check the edit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want seems hard to overcome. I will provide directions. You want the maximum number of variables/factors that are independent. You start by calculating the dot product of binary variables (`df` is your data frame):

```
df = df[df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['Rows','Label','v9'])]]
df.v1.dot(df.v1)

     v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  v10
v1    2   0   0   0   0   1   0   0    2
v2    0   2   0   1   0   0   0   1    0
v3    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0    0
v4    0   1   0   2   0   0   0   1    1
v5    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0    0
v6    1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0    1
v7    0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0    0
v8    0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1    0
v10   2   0   0   1   0   1   0   0    3
```

Now, you want the largest sub-matrix that is all 0 and symmetric. If you complement the above data frame (dot products of columns) binary (converting zeros to 1 and non-zero to 0) and create a graph from it as an adjacency matrix, your problem translates to finding maximum clique problem. Which to the best of my knowledge is *both fixed-parameter intractable and hard to approximate*. However, if the number of variables are small, you probably can find it using brute-forth or approximation algorithms.

Comment: Good thinking. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_in_hypergraphs

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that based on `dtypes`:

```
print(df.columns[df.dtypes != 'float'])

Index(['Rows', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6', 'v7', 'v8', 'v10', 'Label'], dtype='object')
```

You can also do based on count (take columns with 2 unique values)

```
df.columns[df.apply(pd.Series.nunique) == 2]
```

Comment: Some of the binary columns are not a part of one-hot vector, need to find that out too!

Comment: Applying the 'nunique` on columns would only help in verifying that the column is a binary column. Need to find out one 1 and other zeros in a row which is basically a specific combination of columns as there can be some non-hotEncoded/independent binary columns.

Comment: can you post the expected output in your example so I can check.

Comment: Just Improved my question in the post. Thanks for identifying where the question lacked!